# Is there any api (nodejs/python) which allows to share google sheet(given sheet id) with given email

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I have searched in google regarding above question, but could not find any doc specifically, Could some one help with this(Is there any api (nodejs/python) which allows to share google sheet(given sheet id) with given email)

Comment: The Sheets API is for manipulating things specific to the spreadsheet resource. If you want to change generic things, such as file visibility, editors, and such, then use the Google Drive API.

Answer (score 1):

There's a complete python API for Google Sheets: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client oauth2client
```

Same for nodejs: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

```
npm install googleapis@27 --save
```